Notation Clarification for Taylor's Theorem in Higher Dimensions
The following lemma is stated in the coursebook for a paper I am taking on analysis in higher dimensions. (The Lemma is working towards proving Taylor's theorem in higher dimensions).
I am having trouble understanding the notation and was hoping I could seek clarification
$$\varphi^{(k)}(t) = \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_k \in \{1,\dots,n\}} (D_{j_1}\cdots D_{j_k}f)(\gamma (t))h_{j_1}\cdots h_{j_k}$$
The indices are what are confusing me. For a given $k$ is $\sum(D_{j_1}\cdots D_{j_k}f)$ representing the sum of all the mixed partial derivatives of order $k$? (evaluated at $\gamma (t)$ and multiplied by the elements of the vector $\textbf{h}$ of course)
(this is for a $C^{p+1}$ function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $\gamma (t) = a+th$ for $t\in[0,1]$, and $\varphi = f\circ \gamma$).

I assume you use $D_i f$ as your notation for partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f$? If so, I think you are interpreting it correctly.

It might be useful to state the lemma in full to get some context, if you don't mind.

Working out the first few cases, perhaps just $k = 1$ and $k = 2$, should be illustrative.
